# Get element of a newly opened & loaded window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback

While being on a twitter account's page (let's say StackOverflow: https://twitter.com/stackoverflow), I'm trying to get the username of the account, then open a new window querying the account's username on google search. Finally I'd like to get the query text of the newly opened tab.

To do so, I did the following:

```
function getUserName(callback) {
  url = window.location.href;
  console.log(url);
  sn = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
  console.log(sn);
  window.location.href = `https://google.com/search?q=${sn}`;
  callback();
};

function getQuery() {
  console.log(window.location.href);
}

getUserName(getQuery);
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for the new page to be loaded and thus the console.log() form getQuery() is the twitter's one, instead of the google's.

I know this is a matter of callback and await/async, I've been reading a lot about it but those subjects are confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `https://google.com/search?q=${sn}` into a global variable and use that.

Like this:

```
let windowHref = window.location.href;

function getUserName(callback) {
  url = window.location.href;
  console.log(url);
  sn = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
  console.log(sn);

  windowHref = `https://google.com/search?q=${sn}`;
  window.location.href = windowHref;
  callback();
};

function getQuery() {
  console.log(windowHref);
}

getUserName(getQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as getting the `query text of the newly opened tab`. You need make use of the callback function within your `getUserName()` function.

```
function getUserName(callback) {
  url = window.location.href;
  console.log(url);
  sn = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
  console.log(sn);

  windowHref = `https://google.com/search?q=${sn}`;
  callback(windowHref); // Sending back the url to the callback as parameter
};

function getQuery(queryText) { // Value returned from the callback.
  console.log(queryText);
}

getUserName(getQuery);
```

I tried your scenario with linkedin: Sharing the snippets below:

[image: Making the function call]

[image: Getting back value]

Comment: Thanks @imran-rafiq-rather . When I copy paste your code, it gets the query search, but doesn't open a new tab.